# Creating an array of objects in a Laravel form

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to create an array of objects (or a bi-dimensional array) from a form using Laravel

the blade.php looks like

```
@foreach($objets as $objet)
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="objets[]" id="field_A" value="{{$objet->field_A}}">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="objets[]" id="field_B" value="{{$objet->field_B}}">
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Currently, when validating the form, the variable $objets is an array, with all values, but not an array of array.

Comment: Paste the code for `$objets` you can cast into an object for your convenience

Answer (score 1):

Update your input names as follows:

```
<td>
  <input type="text" name="objets[][fieldA]" id="field_A" value="{{$objet->field_B}}">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="text" name="objets[][fieldB]" id="field_B" value="{{$objet->field_B}}">
</td>
```

The above will output an array with array

```
"objects" => array:1 [▼
                0 => array:7 [▼
                   'fieldA' => 'value'
                   'fieldB' => 'value'
                ]
             ]
```

Then in your validation you can use it like this:

```
$validate['objects.*.field_A'] = 'required';
$validate['objects.*.field_B'] = 'required';
return $validate;
```